# Port a MySQL query to Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to setup a one-to-many database, using Doctrine. One User, can have multiple Roles, and when I get the User, I want to get the associated Roles. I have a raw MySQL query that does that.

```
SELECT 
    u.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(r.role) as roles 
FROM 
    users u 
    INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.user_id = u.id 
    INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = ur.role_id
GROUP BY id;

+----+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------+
| id | username | email                  | password                                                     | is_active | GROUP_CONCAT(r.role) |
+----+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------+
|  1 | admin    | my@email.address       | $2a$08$jHZj/wJfcVKlIwr5AvR78euJxYK7Ku5kURNhNx.7.CSIJ3Pq6LEPC |         1 | ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN |
+----+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------+
```

Is this something I can actually automatically replicate in Doctrine? And if so, where abouts am I going wrong? Here are my current (broken) classes (apologies for the code dump).

The error this is currently logging is:

```
[2016-12-20 12:01:35] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\Auth
enticationServiceException(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index: user at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authe
ntication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:94, Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException(code: 0): Notice: Undefined in
dex: user at /var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php:1768)"} []
```

User.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{

    ...

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserRoles", mappedBy="user", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $roles;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));

        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }
    /**
     * Add role
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\UserRoles $role
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addRole(\AppBundle\Entity\UserRoles $role)
    {
        $this->roles[] = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove role
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\UserRoles $role
     */
    public function removeRole(\AppBundle\Entity\UserRoles $role)
    {
        $this->roles->removeElement($role);
    }
}
```

Role.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Role
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="roles")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\RoleRepository")
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $role;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }
}
```

UserRoles.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * UserRoles
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_roles")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRolesRepository")
 */
class UserRoles
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="userroles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Role")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $roleId;


    /**
     * Set userId
     *
     * @param integer $userId
     *
     * @return UserRoles
     */
    public function setUserId($userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    /**
     * Set roleId
     *
     * @param integer $roleId
     *
     * @return UserRoles
     */
    public function setRoleId($roleId)
    {
        $this->roleId = $roleId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get roleId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getRoleId()
    {
        return $this->roleId;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `$roles` association inside your `User` entity you set the `mappedBy` attribute to `user`, but your `UserRoles` entity does not have such a field. Instead it has a field called `userId`. 
Doctrine tries to find the association using your mapping. The `user` value from your `@mappedBy` attribute cannot be found in the database, hence the error message:

> Undefined index...

Since you are mapping objects you should reconsider the naming convention inside your `UserRoles` entity. So don't use `$userId` and `$roleId` but simply use `User` and `Role` and also set dependency injection and return values inside your setters and getters to match `User` and `Role` classes.

Since `UserRoles` is an entity (and not a collection) I would also suggest renaming it to `UserRole` (singular). It will help you understand what you have.

Start with changing your `UserRoles` like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Entity\Role;

/**
 * UserRole
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_roles")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRoleRepository")
 */
class UserRole
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="userRoles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var Role
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Role")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return UserRole
     */
    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param Role $role
     * @return UserRole
     */
    public function setRole(Role $role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

And change your `User` entity to match these changes accordingly:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use AppBundle\Entity\UserRole;
use Serializable;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, Serializable
{  
    ...

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserRole", mappedBy="user", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $userRoles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));

        $this->userRoles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getUserRoles()
    {
        return $this->userRoles;
    }

    /**
     * Add user role
     *
     * @param UserRole $userRole
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addUserRole(UserRole $userRole)
    {
        $this->userRoles[] = $userRole;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove role
     *
     * @param UserRole $userRole
     */
    public function removeUserRole(UserRole $userRole)
    {
        $this->userRoles->removeElement($userRole);
    }
}
```

Since your the repository for your `User` class is called `UserRepository` I also renamed `UserRolesRepository` to `UserRoleRepository` (singular).

Comment: Thanks for that! That's sorted the errors out, and I can now get all the roles for a user. I had to implement the `getRoles()` method for the UserInterface like this, http://pastebin.com/CdbY7PGZ Would you say that's a suitable way, or would there be a better method to do this?

Comment: @TomHart if you only use your `Role` entity for `User` roles then you could also consider creating a many to many relationship with `User` as the owning side. You could in such case remove the whole `UserRole` entity. The code in your pastebin looks fine to me, but I think you can skip the `toArray` part since you should be able to iterate collections directly.

Comment: Okay, I'll try without `toArray`, and I'll do some research on the many to many relationships, and how I might be able to use that. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you cannot figure the ManyToMany out you can always leave another comment...

Comment: After coming across the "Role Hierarchy" stuff, I don't think I actually need a x to x relationship at the moment, but I'm sure something will come up where I need to use it :)